# Mass update instance name

Tags: apex, trigger

We are moving from one instance(na2) to other instance(na27). Is there anyway to mass update all templates, triggers, pages,validation rules in one shot rather than going and searching for each and every code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to move metadata to the new instance. If  you are moving metadata, you can use either Eclipse or force.com migration tool.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do by copying metadata of one org to other org using metadata api or available tools like Force.com IDE. For code though you will need to make a copy on your local machine (you could use Force.com IDE or sublime Text 3 with mavens mate) and then push the code to your new org. This should be done once your metadata is uploaded.

Comment: Sounds like this is a pod migration, i.e. they're looking for a global find and replace for the pod. I'm pretty sure there's nothing like that other than an actual global search and replace.